# How to present multiple next/previous links in ASP.NET Wizard control?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wizard

I am using a layout template for an ASP.NET Wizard control:

```
  <LayoutTemplate>
     <div style="position: relative; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; overflow: auto">
        <div class="wizsidebar">          
           <asp:PlaceHolder ID="sideBarPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
           <div style="clear: both">             
              <asp:PlaceHolder ID="navigationPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wizstep">
           <!-- Want navigation here... -->
           <asp:PlaceHolder ID="WizardStepPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
           <!-- ...and here -->

        </div>
     </div>
  </LayoutTemplate>
```

I would like to have the navigation (next/previous buttons) show up at the top and bottom of each step, as well as in the sidebar. Is this possible with the Wizard control or do I have to mimic the behavior with buttons of my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your buttons have CommandName="MovePrevious" and CommandName="MoveNext" they will cause the navigation

Comment: Thanks. Added an example (what I ended up doing) and marked as answer.